# How to access a named logger in a dictConfig? i.e. not root

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am using a dictConfig to configure my logging:

```
logconfig = {
'version': 1,

'disable_existing_loggers': False,

'formatters': {'standard': {'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s', 'datefmt': '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'}, },

'handlers': {'debug': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'formatter': 'standard', 'class': 'logging.FileHandler', 'filename': 'Ops Log Debug.log', },
             'general': {'level': 'INFO', 'formatter': 'standard', 'class': 'logging.FileHandler', 'filename': 'Ops Log.log', }, },

'loggers': {'': {'handlers': ['debug'], 'level': 'DEBUG', 'propagate': False},
            'mainlogger': {'handlers': ['general'], 'level': 'INFO', 'propagate': False}, } }
```

In case it matters, it is stored in a separate .py file and imported into my main script.
The code I'm using to run it is:

```
import LoggerConfig  
import logging  
logging.config.dictConfig(LoggerConfig.logconfig)  
my_logger = logging.getLogger('main')
```

How do I get my script to use the 'mainlogger' logger in my dict instead of root?
Am I going about this the wrong way? - I wanted 2 loggers: 1 for debug level+ and 1 for info level+ each writing to their own file.

Comment: `logging.getLogger('mainlogger')`?

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. I think it relates to the name of the logger on output, as it prints that as the name in the formatter part.